# Employee integrity problem

Tags: ethics

An employee on my team decided to run a superbowl pool and invited other employees into the pool (I was not made aware of the pool). The entry fee was $6; total payouts $550 with the remaining $50 going to her for running the pool.  Three other team members had winning numbers, total payout $400.  No one has been paid. The pool administrator used the funds collected for her own personal use and now cannot pay anyone. I feel this behavior is unscrupulous and fraudulent and I’d like to terminate the employee.  There is a real integrity issue on the team but my HR department won’t support termination. How do I handle this?

Comment: Is SuperBowl pool betting legal at your location? What is HR suggesting instead of termination?

Comment: This is fraud and be legally prosecuted.

Comment: This needs some more details: What is your position? Peer? Manager? HR? And why do want to terminate the employee? As punishment? Because you feel you can no longer work with them? Because you fear they will defraud the company, too?

Comment: It is wrong, it is not legal, and HR does not support termination.  Suck it up.  This person is going to suffer harsh retaliation just sit back and let it happen.

Comment: $400 is peanuts. A friend of mine lent money to a woman who claimed she had cancer and needed it for an operation. In total, the woman borrowed about *a hundred thousand dollars* from friends and colleagues and absconded with the money.

Comment: Did HR give you any alternatives? Did the accused person give any alternatives (like: don't have the money now, I'll pay you from my next paycheck)?

Comment: And in case someone suggests it, garnishing her wages to pay back the other employees is ***not*** acceptable. You may have a right to terminate her for lack of integrity and trust, but the personal financial dealings of your employees are not company business.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this would result in termination by HR. To give an example, someone at my job got fired because she kept stealing food from someone else's desk. They installed a camera to catch her, as the employee was wondering who kept stealing her energy bar.

As your HR does not support this claim as valid for termination, I would say to talk to your manager about her as you can't trust her anymore, and indirectly she destroys any teamwork. I think it will be difficult to have a productive team meeting if she's there with coworkers she stole from.

In the short term, the fact she stole from her coworkers will make her job a nightmare. To give another example from where I work, someone stole the coffee pot money - we have a good idea who it is, but as we don't have any proof we still talk about it 7 years later (and it was only a 30$ steal). Luckily for the one that stole, he got moved 3-4 months after the incident.

A talk with her would maybe clear up why she did it, maybe she has difficulty in her personal life, but the trust is lost, nothing will bring it back easily.

Comment: Fixed a couple typos, I assume "mutated" was a typo :) Could you clarify the process of installing the camera - who did it, who gave permission? That may be helpful for readers, as installing a camera on your own initiative could be illegal in some jurisdictions.

Comment: You could formally go  over HR's head to the CEO and say that you have lost trust in HR to act professionally

Comment: @Neuromancer That step seem drastic, but my tip to escalate to his superior will kinda lead there. As his superior will be able to escalate the case to the hr boss directly. For like a team leader to directly escalate that it can be badly seen. It depend on the OP position in the compagny